# jQuery replace hide and show with detach/append not working

Tags: jquery

I don't want any content loading , and wish only to have the content load when you select an option value , i tried replace hide with detach and show with append , but can't get this working.

I will have about 50 items to select from , and i don't want all that content loading and slowing down the load time, so i only want each div content to display as i select them.

The content for each of the modules is a provided shortcut to the data from the host.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.module_container').hide();
        $('#Moduleselect').change(function () {
            $('.module_container').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
        });
    });



<select id="Moduleselect">
  <option value="">Select Module</option>
  <option value="selectmodule_1">Module Name</option>
  <option value="selectmodule_2">Module Name</option>
  <option value="selectmodule_3">Module Name</option>
  <option value="selectmodule_4">Module Name</option>
</select>
    <div id="selectmodule_1" class="module_container"><module name="ALL_MY_LEAGUES"/></div>
    <div id="selectmodule_2" class="module_container"><module name="LAST_WEEKS_FANTASY_RESULTS"/></div>
    <div id="selectmodule_3" class="module_container"><module name="FANTASY_ARTICLES"/></div>
    <div id="selectmodule_4" class="module_container"><module name="DRAFT_STATUS"/></div>
```

Comment: your code  looks fine so what is the problem???

Comment: code is fine, but not doing what i need. I don't want any of the content to load in the DOM , only want is shown as each option is selected

Comment: @MShack "wish only to have the content load when you select an option value"...you want to load the content via ajax?? or this content is already there in your page and you want to show this specific content....can you put up a fiddle for this??

Comment: the host provides shortcuts to different modules , so in each .module_container i will be calling out different one. Example of the content would be <module name="ALL_MY_LEAGUES"/>

Comment: so you want to make div's with jquery or just want to show existing div's in dom with jquery??

Comment: @MShack how will you be calling out different modules using host...can you show it in your code??

Comment: i edited my post to show exactly how the modules are called out in HTML , then the host populates the data based on those module names